# Rendering Selected Values Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, post, html-select

I have a select list;

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="blabla" name="FirmIds" multiple data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" data-selected-text-format="count>1">
</select>
```

Its members are coming from BD.

I want to post the selected values,

When I select more than 1 options, only the last selected element's value comes.

```
$FirmIds = $_POST['FirmIds'];
```

What should I do to retrieve all selected option's values

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the final answer:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="firmIds[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
```

```
<?php
    $result = $_POST['firmIds']; 
    foreach($result as $res){ 
      echo($res) ; 
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit you select name attribute to receive a select array adding '[]' like this :

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="blabla" name="FirmIds[]" multiple data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" data-selected-text-format="count>1">
  //Your options here
</select>
```

With this solution you will be able to manage the selected values as an array in PHP, ...

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. How can I retrieve the posted values ? for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){ $data_array[] = $_POST[$FirmIds['$i']];}, but it is not working